# How to download Gzip file from remote machine using JSch

Tags: java, scp, jsch

I'm trying to download a .gz file from a linux remote machine using Jsch

Jsch clearly works for normal files, but it doesn't for Gzip/zip file. InputStream.read returns that it cannot find such file.
Also any pointers how to download directory from remote machine ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to replicate that java code into an scp command and run it with any success?

Comment: As per @alok's comment, try any standalone SCP client first. Post any code, logs, etc.

Comment: Jsch shouldn't have any unusual problems with gz or zip files. Please edit your question to include the code you are using to download these files, and the exact error messages that you're getting.

Comment: And, well, some code could be helpful.

Comment: scp command doesn't work on windows , as it doesn't have a port listening.I would like to develop a tool that works alike on windows and linux as well. @alok .

Comment: The code is at this place. http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html @MarkusWMahlberg. The code works for .log,.txt,etc.  But it doesn't for .gz file

Comment: **Your** code, Jokester!

Comment: `scp command doesn't work on windows` - Sure it does. Check mingw. Also, sharing code would help because I've written code that copies \*.\* and deals mostly with .gz and .bzip files. Never saw a problem there.

Comment: Also as far as this is concerned: `I would like to develop a tool that works alike on windows and linux as well`  - There's this cross-platform IDE called Eclipse. You can install remoting plugins to perform SSH/SFTP operations.

Comment: the issue has been resolved, we need to set                                   Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);  before connecting with the session.

Comment: sure thanks @alok , Jcraft is the plugin I have been using for the download, on eclipse.